# Android. Reading a database from an external folder

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

I need help. I can't solve my problem.

I need to restore the database from a previously saved file, which is located somewhere in the phone memory.

I open the file selection screen and get it in `onActivityResult`. My code here are below.

```
private void onClickButtonRestoreFromFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    if (!FileManager.getInstance().selectFileDataBase(this)) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

         if (resultData == null || !FileManager.getInstance().checkFileType(resultData.getData().getPath())) {
        //if (resultData == null) {
            MessageDialogView.showErrorResultMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.Message_Error_Open_File));
            return;
        }

        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put(NavigationManagerKeyParameters.RESTORE_DATA_BASE_ACTIVITY_DATA, resultData.getData().getPath());
        NavigationManager.getInstance().navigateTo(NavigationManager.Pages.RestoreDataBaseActivity, parameters);
    }
}
```

The URI I get from `resultData.getData().getPath()` depending on the android version is different. For example on Android 9 (device) `resultData.getData().getPath()` returns something like ***"/ external/storage/.../file.sqlite"***. The same answer I get on Android 5.1 (emulator).

However, on Android 5.1 (Xaiomi) I get something like ***"content://.../432"***

**Why do I get the URI in different formats?**

After that, I copy my database file to a temporary file inside the application memory. I do it in the following way:

```
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream input = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH);

    //перемещаем байты из входящего файла в исходящий
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
}
```

Where `DB_NAME` is the name of the temporary file and `DB_PATH` is the path to the user-selected file. After these steps, I read the data from the temporary database file and transfer it to the working database.

**Am I doing everything right? Or is this problem solved in a different way?**

In General, my task is to restore the user's database from the saved copy that he chooses.

Please help me solve my problem. I repeat them:

1. Why on different versions of Android `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` returns different URIs to the file. How do I add uniform behavior?
2. Am I solving the problem of database recovery correctly by copying the file to the application memory and then reading it out and writing it to the database?

Comment: Why don't use asset folder to put your database

Comment: @vimukthi What do you mean? Please explain in more detail?

Comment: In there you have problem with path of the external database. so you can use assets folder to  solve those problem you faced in there.

Comment: @vimukthi The user chooses where his file with the database is located. It can be SD card, phone memory, GDrive, OneDrive, etc. 

Or do you offer to move the selected file to the Assets folder, and only then work with it?